# Cast dynamic to List<T>

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

```
private static void GetData()
{
   dynamic dynamicList =FetchData();
   FilterAndSortDataList(dynamicList);
}

private static void FilterAndSortDataList<T>(List<T> dataList)
{
    ...
}
```

I am getting a runtime binding error when I call FilterAndSortDataList. Is there a way to cast my dynamicList to `List<T>` at runtime?

Note that FetchData() is implimented by plugins, so I don't know in advance what the type T is.

Comment: It needs to actually *be* a list for that to work.  The fact that it gives that error means that the object isn't actually a list.

Comment: There may be some help here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5014235 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513952

Comment: What kind of object is actually in the `dynamic` variable?  In other words, what does `FetchData()` return?

Answer (score 8):

I see no reason why it should fail, unless `FetchData` is improper data.

Possibility I: `FetchData` is returning null, and hence the type parameter cannot be figured out (null has no type in C#).

Possibility II: `FetchData` is not returning a proper `List<T>` object.

I would redesign the thing like:

```
private static void GetData()
{
   dynamic dynamicList = FetchData();

   if (dynamicList is IEnumerable) //handles null as well
       FilterAndSortDataList(Enumerable.ToList(dynamicList));

   //throw; //better meaning here.
}
```

It checks whether the returned type is `IEnumerable` (hoping that it is some `IEnumerable<T>` - we cant check if it is `IEnumerable<T>` itself since we dont have `T` with us. Its a decent assumption) in which case we convert the obtained sequence to `List<T>`, just to be sure we are passing a `List<T>`. `dynamic` wont work with extension methods, so we have to call `Enumerable.ToList` unfortunately. In case `dynamicList` is null or not an enumerable it throws which gives it better meaning than some run time binding error.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to cast my dynamicList to List at runtime

I don't know why you declare it as dynamic when it has to be a `List<T>`, but I'm guessing it is because you don't know what `T` is.  If you *did*, you could just directly cast it:

```
private static void GetData()
{
   dynamic dynamicList = new List<string> ();
   FilterAndSortDataList((List<string>)dynamicList);
}

private static void FilterAndSortDataList<T>(List<T> dataList)
{
    ...
}
```

but obviously that could fail at runtime.

Another option might be to make `GetData` generic as well:

```
private static void GetData<T>()
{
   List<T> list = new List<T>();
   FilterAndSortDataList(list);
}

private static void FilterAndSortDataList<T>(List<T> dataList)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: After `dynamic dynamicList = new List<string> ();` dynamicList is `List<string>` and no need to cast.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: Yeah, I think D's point is that the element type is not known at compile time.

Comment: @RobertHarvey If you don't know element type at compile time you can't cast it directly. :)

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: So true.  But there are some magic tricks that might work; see the comments I posted below the OP.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It doesn't matter whether he knows the type at compile time or not, since he's using `dynamic`.  Clearly the actual value is an array or a string or something that's not any kind of list, since it failed.  If it was any kind of list, even if he doesn't know the generic argument at compile time, then his code would work.

Comment: @RobertHarvey As I [said from the start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18151018/cast-dynamic-to-listt/18151114?noredirect=1#comment26585617_18151018) for it to fail requires the actual object within the variable to not actually be a list.  Without knowing what it actually is, we can't know how to turn it into a list.

Comment: @Servy I did, in fact, agree with you.

Comment: since I don't know the type at compile time, this doesn't work.

Comment: @BrokeMyLegBiking: To cast it to a `List<T>` you will have to divine what's in the dynamic, and then perform some sort of reflection magic to reflect over the members and stuff them into a list.